# saber si existe un id en una tabla

Tags: java

como puedo hacer para consultar si un dato existe en una columna de una tabla; yo quiero hacer una función en java para realizar la consulta y que me devuelva un mensaje pero yo le paso el parámetro.

tengo lo siguiente:

```
public static String existeID(String identificacion){
    String msg="";
    Connection cnConexion=Database.getConexion();
    PreparedStatement psID=null;
    ResultSet rID=null;
    try{
        String consulta = "SELECT nombres, apellidos from persona where cedula = 'identificacion'";
        psID = cnConexion.prepareStatement(consulta);

        rID = psID.executeQuery();
        if(){//no vacio
            msg = "ID pertenece a: "+rID.getString("nombres")+rID.getString("apellidos");
        }
        else{
            msg = "Puede usarla";
        }            
    }
    catch(SQLException e){

    }                
    return msg;
}
```

en sí quiero realizar la consulta porque la columna no está con ID único y por el momento puedo duplicar este dato, me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema.
(estoy trabajando en netbeans y la base de datos es Catalina)

Gracias

Comment: Estas armando mal el query. le tendrias que concatenar el valor que estas trayendo. Vos no estas haciendo eso. Esa es tu duda?

Comment: verás no tengo alguna idea de como dar solución a este requerimiento, estuve consultando sobre esto. lo que quiero seria realizar la consulta de que no existe y en caso de que no haya una identificación similar me mande un mensaje de que puedo continuar; la identificación es el parámetro que paso, no te entiendo que hay que concatenar si esta que la columna cedula tenga el valor del parámetro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te cuento 1º mezclas churras con merinas una cosa es el método otra la conexión a la base de datos y otra el main que es donde imprimes los mensaje. yo he pensado algo así no se si esta correcto del todo.
en la clase conexión creas el método para conectarte y los método para mirar en base de datos y consultar.
En el main llamas al método y ya le haces los print del resultado por ejemplo if(base_datos.existeID(String identificacion) =true) system.out print("id disponible")

```
public ConectorBD() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Conección a base de datos " + bd + ". lista");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        conn = null;
        System.out.println("La conexion a la  base de datos " + bd + " ha terminado");
    }
public boolean existeID(String identificacion) {
        boolean disponible = false;
        try {
            Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
            orden.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) from persona where cedula = '" + identificacion"'");
            orden.close();
            disponible = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return disponible;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos te sugiero realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
String selectSQL = "SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM persona WHERE cedula = ?";
try {
    dbConnection = Database.getConexion();
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1234567890);

    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Como te comentaron solo falta colocar bien tu concatenación.

Fuente: [PreparedStatement](http://www.chuidiang.org/java/mysql/PreparedStatement-java-mysql.php)

Answer (score 0):

Como dice gbianchi, te falta concatenar tu variable:

String consulta = "SELECT nombres, apellidos from persona where cedula = " + identificacion + "";

Comment: OJO con la inyección SQL.